# How many arguments an MVC action can have?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any document about maxinum number of arguments we can pass to an action in ASP.net MVC?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are doing something that might hit the max even remotely then you really should reconsider what you are doing :)

Comment: Absolutely, but I'm really curious about that and do not want it to be a gray area. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is no limit on the number of arguments - your main limitation wouild be the maximum HTML request/header lengths imposed by both the browser and server.